# The same form_for works differently in different views. I've got it working, but...why does it work this way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-for

[Gist (includes examples of both forms used and relevant excerpts from the controllers](https://gist.github.com/nonsenseless/ce9231a03f4548b87514)

So I'm building an application modeled off Facebook. Post#Index is where Users go to see posts and comments (a la Timeline). User#Show is where Users go to see their profile and *also* post and comment.

Post#Index worked swimmingly and comments were created and destroyed without problem:

```
<%= form_for([post, post.comments.build], url: post_comments_path(post.id) ) do |f| %>
    <p><%= f.text_area :comment %></p>
    <p><%= f.submit %> </p>
<% end %>
```

But when I went to incorporate the same form into the profile on User#Show , it kept throwing me an error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments", :post_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:post_id]
```

Now that's odd. Both of the partials involved are rendering a collection of posts and passing in the same variables, why is one not able to see the post id?

I thought that perhaps post wasn't getting passed in properly, but when I used eRB to parse <%= post.id %>, the page processed and displayed all the post IDs without a problem.

I eventually reached 'a' solution shown in the second form block:

```
<%= form_for([post, post.comments.build], url: "/posts/#{post.id}/comments" ) do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.text_area :comment %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit %> </p>
<% end %>
```

This works for both locations, so that's great (if brittle), but I still have no idea why one worked and the other didn't. Can anybody help me get a better understanding of what's going on here?

(Note: I know CommentsController needs to be cleaned up.)

Comment: I can't find where you define `post` variable. Most likely yoour views are just rendering your form as a partial and are passing different items as local `post`? Also note that even though the second option seems to work, you won't be able to submit the form as you have blank in the url. The exception were warning you about this.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that you are trying to create a form, which would create a comments on the non-existing post (you used @posts.build - this record is not yet stored in the database). To help you any further you need to give some more details on what you are trying to achieve - why do you build a post when displying a user is a total mystery for me.

Comment: You're right on the money with regard to the partials passing items to post. I opted to leave them out initially. I updated the gist with cuts of the relevant partial.      With regard to why: as noted in the first paragraph, it's meant to be modeled off Facebook where users can post on their profile page as well as on the 'root' page.   With regard to post.build...that record *does* exist as the comments form is only called on existing posts. I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Did you try to specify the method? `<%= form_for([post, post.comments.build], url: post_comments_path(post.id) , method: 'post') do |f| %>`

Comment: Archana: Yes'm, but to no avail, I'm afraid. Same URL Generation error as above.

Comment: Problem lies here: `post_comments_path(post.id)`, - `post.id` is `nil`, ergo `post` is not saved in the database.

Comment: @BroiSatse But, if that's the case, why does ""/posts/#{post.id}/comments""  work when it's referring to the exact same post id?

Comment: @nonsenseless - it works in sense it does not raise an exception. However check your form, you'll see it is submitting to `posts//comments` - you will get an exception when submitting the form.

Comment: @BroiSatse As I said before, it *is* posting successfully, the form submits properly, the comment is created. The HTML output of the form is "form class="new_comment" id="new_comment" action="/posts/34/comments" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">". There is no exception raised. The comment persists. I promise, there is no exception.